# Conditional Validation RequiredIf field required for more than one type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

If you can't apply the same data annotation twice to one property as follows:

```
[RequiredIf("Country", "Canada", "Postal Code is Required") ]
[RequiredIf("Country", "France", "Postal Code is Required") ]
public string PostalCode { get; set; }
```

How would you check that the postal code is required for more than one country?

Comment: My recommendation would be to do it in the code itself before it get's sent to the db or whatever storage.

I'm not sure how that method works, but if it accepted methods you may be able to us a list and a contains

Comment: [Conditional Validation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2011/02/04/conditional-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can just write your own custom validator for this and place it ontop of your model, not property. Something like this is quick and *?dirty?* way of doing this.

```
// Not guaranteed to work since I work only with FluentValidation for past year
public class PostalCodeValidator : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var address = (Address)value;

        if ((address.Country == "Canada" || address.Country == "France") && address.PostalCode == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

I highly recommend learning and using [FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) on your next projects since it will divide validation from model itself and make validation a lot easier in general.